# Orthogonal matrices show that the product is also orthogonal

Tags: matrices, inverse, orthogonality

Show that if A and B are two orthogonal n × n matrices, then so is AB

I know orthogonal is when the transpose of the matrix is equal to it's inverse.

Please help

Comment: Have you tried taking the transpose of $AB$? What is $(AB)^T$ in terms of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: its it the transpose of B times the transpose of A?

Comment: Right.  And what do you know about $A^T$ and $B^T$?  Here, I'll put it in an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Very simple, $(AB)(AB)^T=(AB)(B^TA^T)=A(BB^T)A^T=AIA^T=I$, then $AB$ is orthogonal

Answer (score 2):

Another characterization is that $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix **iff** $\|Qx\|_2=\|x\|_2$ for all $x$.

Then $\|ABx\|_2 = \|Bx\|_2 = \|x\|_2$ for all $x$, hence $AB$ is orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

$(AB)^T=B^TA^T=B^{-1}A^{-1}=(AB)^{-1}$ and so AB is orthogonal.